# Rewriting url in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

i have setup a website and using IIS7, now what i want to do is when user hits the domain, it should take the user to another page, for example say user hits m.abc.com, url should be rewrited to m.abc.com/section/news, however /section/news should not be displayed in the addressbar, but the page should be news, in short i want url rewrite directly on root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways for doing url rewriting:

1. Using IIS add-in: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite
2. Using asp.net url wriritng with http handlers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

Answer (score 1):

IIS has an add-in that you can install just for this purpose

http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite